# Java Reflections error: Wrong number of arguments

Tags: java, reflection, constructor

So I'm trying to invoke a classes constructor at runtime. I have the following code snippet:

```
String[] argArray = {...};
...
Class<?> tempClass = Class.forName(...);
Constructor c = tempClass.getConstructor(String[].class); 
c.newInstance(argArray);
...
```

Whenever I compile the code and pass it a class, I get an IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments. The constructor of the class I'm calling takes in a String[] as the only argument. What's also weird is that if I change the constructor to take in an integer and use Integer.TYPE and call c.newInstance(4) or something, it works. Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Edit;; Complete error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
[Ljava.lang.String;@2be3d80c
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Could you post the complete error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is the best fix but this should work:

```
c.newInstance((Object)argArray);
```

Comment: Without the Object[] wrapper newInstance tries to pass multiple String arguments to a single argument constructor. The exception message changes from (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch) to (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments) depending on the size of the String array.

Answer (score 12):

This is happening because [`newInstance(Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29) takes [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) of `Object`, in other words `Object[]`. Since arrays are covariant, a `String[]` is also an `Object[]`, and `argArray` is being interpretted as *all arguments* instead of *first argument*.

[jdb's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14491805/697449) works because it prevents the compiler from misunderstanding. You could also write:

```
c.newInstance(new Object[] {argArray});
```